# NASM Hello World either segfaults or bus errors in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, nasm, bus-error

I'm writing Hello World in NASM, and I can get it to echo `Hello World` to the console, but the program segfaults if I don't run it with Make.

Trace with Makefile:

```
$ make
nasm -f macho -o hello.o --prefix _ hello.asm
ld -o hello hello.o -arch i386 -lc -macosx_version_min 10.6 -e _start -no_pie
./hello
Hello World!
```

Trace with manual commands:

```
$ nasm -f macho -o hello.o --prefix _ hello.asm
$ ld -o hello hello.o -arch i386 -lc -macosx_version_min 10.6 -e _start -no_pie
$ ./hello 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

hello.asm:

```
[bits 32]

section .data

msg: db "Hello World!", 0

section .text

global start
extern puts
extern exit

start:

push msg
call puts
add esp, 4

push 0
call exit
```

Makefile:

```
# Linux defaults

FORMAT=-f elf
MINV=
ARCH=-arch i386
LIBS=
RUN=./
EXECUTABLE=hello
PREFIX=
ENTRY=
PIE=

# Windows
ifeq (${MSYSTEM},MINGW32)
    FORMAT=-f win32
    EXECUTABLE=hello.exe
    PREFIX=--prefix _
    ENTRY=-e _start
    ARCH=
    LIBS=c:/strawberry/c/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/crt2.o -Lc:/strawberry/c/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32
    ENTRY=
    RUN=
endif

# Mac OS X
ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Darwin)
    FORMAT=-f macho
    PREFIX=--prefix _
    ENTRY=-e _start
    LIBS=-lc
    MINV=-macosx_version_min 10.6
    PIE=-no_pie
endif

all: test

test: $(EXECUTABLE)
    $(RUN)$(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): hello.o
    ld -o $(EXECUTABLE) hello.o $(ARCH) $(LIBS) $(MINV) $(ENTRY) $(PIE)

hello.o: hello.asm
    nasm $(FORMAT) -o hello.o $(PREFIX) hello.asm

clean:
    -rm $(EXECUTABLE)
    -rm hello.o
```

Specs:

- ld 64-134.9
- LLVM 3.1svn
- NASM 0.98.40
- Make 3.81
- Xcode 4.5
- Mac OS X 10.8.1
- MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: Update: I got rid of the bus error by using libc's `exit(0)`. However, the program still segfaults unless it is run by Make.

Comment: That's weird, I closed Terminal.app and tried building hello.asm again. Now it no longer segfaults when I manually run it.

Answer (score 3):

2 things, your hello world string is not NULL terminated and as I mentioned in another post, when you use C functions, you MUST adjust esp after each call

Comment: He doesn't need to adjust `esp` here because he destroys the stack frame right afterwards.

Comment: He is learning Assembly, learn to to things the correct way in the beginning, no matter how trivial and it will save headaches later.

Comment: @Gunner, upvote, but please supply the improved code. When I null-terminate the Hello World string and adjust esp after the `puts` call, my program still segfaults.

Comment: Is ret a valid way to return control to the OS?  It is not in Windows nor Linux, that is probably the reason for the segfault, don't have a MAC but just a ret, makes Linux and Windows throw a hissy fit.

Answer (score 2):

You tore down your stack frame twice:

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
...
leave
```

You only need one of those, since `leave` is equivalent to `mov esp, ebp; pop ebp`.

See http://michaux.ca/articles/assembly-hello-world-for-os-x for several example hello world programs. Note that all of them exit the program explicitly with

```
; 2a prepare the argument for the sys call to exit
push dword 0              ; exit status returned to the operating system

; 2b make the call to sys call to exit
mov eax, 0x1              ; system call number for exit
sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) system calls needs "extra space" on stack
int 0x80                  ; make the system call
```

because you cannot `ret` from an entry point (there's nothing to return to).

Also note that if you call the function `main` and don't supply the `e` option to `ld`, then `libc`'s entry point will be called. In that case, it is permissible to `ret` since you will return control to `libc` (which calls `exit` on your behalf).

Comment: Can you supply a full hello.asm that doesn't segfault or bus error on Mac OS X?

Comment: I solved the bus error by using libc's `exit(0)`, but I still get a segfault unless I run the program from Make. See my updated code in the original post.